# Application runs with a "println" method, but crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS when it's removed

Tags: ios, swift, exc-bad-access

I have the following `applicationWillEnterForeground` method code, with the next println method: `println("nextUpdate unwrapped")`. If this print exists then the application runs without issues, as soon as I remove/comment out this println method the application crashes with **EXC_BAD_ACCESS** but the location of the error is not specified in the console, so I have no idea what is crashing my app.

```
func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication!) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the
    // inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on
    // entering the background.

    countForWill++
    var timeIntervalSince1970: NSTimeInterval!
    Logger.printLogToConsole(TAG, aMethodName: __FUNCTION__, aMessage: "Runs for the \(countForWill) time")

    var lastUpdateTimeStamp: AnyObject? = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().doubleForKey(KiboConstants.UserDefaultsStrings.USER_DEF_LAST_UPDATE_TIME_STAMP)
    var nextUpdate: AnyObject? = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().doubleForKey(KiboConstants.UserDefaultsStrings.USER_DEF_NEXT_UPDATE)
    if let lastUpdateTimeStampUnwrapped: AnyObject = lastUpdateTimeStamp {

        if let nextUpdateUnwrapped: AnyObject = nextUpdate {
            println("nextUpdate unwrapped")

            let lastUpdateTimeStampUnwrappedDouble: Double = lastUpdateTimeStampUnwrapped as Double
            var nextUpdateUnwrappedDouble: Double = nextUpdateUnwrapped as Double
            nextUpdateUnwrappedDouble = nextUpdateUnwrappedDouble * 60

            //var nextUpdateTimeStamp: Double = (lastUpdateTimeStampUnwrapped as Double) + (nextUpdateUnwrapped as Double * 60)
            var nextUpdateTimeStamp: Double = lastUpdateTimeStampUnwrappedDouble + nextUpdateUnwrappedDouble
            timeIntervalSince1970 = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
            if (nextUpdateTimeStamp < timeIntervalSince1970) {
                checkForNewSources()
            } else {
                let updatedNextUpdate = nextUpdateTimeStamp - NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
                setTimeWithNextUpdateValue(updatedNextUpdate)
            }
        } else {
            var nextUpdateTimeStamp: Double = (lastUpdateTimeStampUnwrapped as Double) + (DEFAULT_NEXT_UPDATE_VAL * 60)
            timeIntervalSince1970 = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
            if (nextUpdateTimeStamp < timeIntervalSince1970) {
                checkForNewSources()
            } else {
                let updatedNextUpdate = nextUpdateTimeStamp - timeIntervalSince1970
                setTimeWithNextUpdateValue(updatedNextUpdate)
            }
        }
    } else {
        checkForNewSources()
    }

    let topViewController = self.IndexNavigationController.topViewController
    if topViewController is HelloViewController {

        var found: Bool = false
        found = SystemUtils.CommonTasks.isKiboKeyboardEnabled()
        if found {
            let activateViewController = ActivateViewController()
            self.IndexNavigationController.pushViewController(activateViewController, animated: false)
        }
    }
}
```

Now, obviously this is a timing bug, but I'm just started to develop for the iOS and I have no idea how to debug and fix this issue.

Comment: I actually see why your app could crash, but I don't see any link between this and the `println` statement. If you don't see where the app crashes, try to do a step-by-step debugging, starting from just above the `println` line?

Comment: Turning on `NSZombieMode` should help debug too.